# Can memory returned to the main function by value be freed using delete?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The way I understood this when I learned about it was that the C++ keyword delete can only safely delete memory that was allocated by new. I'm wondering if you can return a struct by value from a function, and delete it in main. Here is an example of what I'm asking...

```
#include <stdio>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

struct structure {
   int i;
   float f;
}

struct get_struct();

int main() {
   structure structure_1;
   structure_1 = get_struct();

   delete &structure_1;
   return 0;
}

struct get_struct() {
   struct test_struct = new struct;
   return test_struct;
}
```

I know that I could just return a pointer from the function and assign a pointer in main to point to the return value of the function, that's not what I'm asking. I've also tried to delete using...

```
delete &struct;
```

This doesn't work though and I get a Visual Studio error.

So what I'm asking is, does anyone know of a way to return a structure from a function by value with new, and use delete to free that memory in main. Maybe it's a very simple task, but I'm stumped. Thanks everyone!

Comment: `struct` is a keyword, you can't use it as the name of a variable

Comment: Please for your own sanity don't use pointers in C++

Comment: I think you should review your `get_struct()` first before worrying about deleting anything. You're trying to assign pointer to `struct` to `struct` object... Not to mention using `struct` as a variable name...

Comment: This is **not good example code** for the question you're asking.  There are many errors unrelated to your question.  Please fix them and post *that* code so we don't have to guess what you really meant to type.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of thought, I am moving the proper solution to the top:

```
struct S { int a; S(int a) : a(a) { } };
S foo () { return S(5); }

int main() {
    S s = foo();
}
```

This solution *won't* copy S; it will be moved instead. Since it involves no manual memory management, it's safer and thus recommended.

---

If it's a stupid assignment, and you absolutely have to use `new`:

```
struct S {};

S* foo () { return new S; }

int main () {
    S* ptr = foo();
    delete ptr;
}
```

But it's not considered modern C++; you can safely return  by value, since the compiler will opt-out any copies.

Answer (score 0):

### General part

The general answer to your question is **no**, you can't.

- The `new` and `delete` operators always deal with pointers, not with any other value type.
- You will never have to delete any value type by hand and really never, never, never (!) ever should try to so.

The reason is, that the memory used to store any value is allocated from a different part of the main memory as the memory used to store the values that pointers as returned by the `new` operator point to.

The memory location that is used to store the values used in your function called **stack** will be automatically allocated once program flow enters the function and automatically cleaned up once the function is left.

(Well of course internally there has some work to be done to accomplish this but you will never have to deal with it yourself, as the compiler will generate the needed setup and cleanup code)

Memory used to store the values that pointers generated with the `new` operator on the other hand are allocated from another part of the memory (often called *heap*) that doesn't automatically get cleaned up at all.

### By your example

Taking a look at your example code:

```
struct get_struct() {
   struct test_struct = new struct;
   return test_struct;
}
```

The first problem is, that even after fixing up some syntactic errors:

```
struct structure get_struct() {
   struct structure test_struct = new structure;
   return test_struct;
}
```

The code will not compile with the compiler throwing some error like:

```
error: conversion from ‘structure*’ to non-scalar type ‘structure’ requested
```

As using `new structure` not the value, but only a pointer to that value will be available.
To make both types match you would have to use `struct strcuture *test_test = new structure;` To still return by value you might come to the idea to do something like this:

```
struct structure get_struct() {
   struct structure *test_struct = new structure;
   return *test_struct;
}
```

Which in would return by value making a copy of the data allocated for test_struct.

The problem with this approach is, that now you have generated a memory hole, as you will see by taking a closer look at what will be happening:

- on entering the function enough memory to hold the value of a pointer to a `struct structure` will be allocated on the stack.
- the `new` opertor will allocate some memory to hold a `struct structure` on the *heap*, which is the common name for the other part of memory I already talked about.
- a pointer to this memory location will be stored in test_struct
- a copy of the struct structure pointed at by test_struct will be made.
- the memory allocated to store the value of the pointer to `struct structure` when the function was entered will be freed.

The problem with this approach is, that on leaving get_structure only pointer, but not the data pointed at was given back to the system. As you didn't keep any copy of it that memory is effectively lost as there is no chance to reference it in any `delete` statement again.

What happened is the following:

```
             call to                    return
  main()    --------->  get_struct()    -------->
           get_struct()                            
 STACK
  +--------------+      +--------------+        +--------------+
  | structure_1; |      | structure_1  |        | structure_1  |
  +--------------+      +--------------+        +--------------+
  |              |      | ...          |        |              |
                        |              |
                        | test_struct *--+
                        +--------------+ | 
                        |              | |
                                         |              
 HEAP                                    |
                                         |
  |              |      |              | |      |              |
  |              |      +--------------+ |      +--------------+
  |              |      | structure    |<+      | structure    |
  |              |      | data         |        | data         |
  +--------------+      +--------------+        +--------------+
```

To prevent memory loss you would have had to `delete` it before leaving `get_structure()`, probably using something like:

```
struct structure get_struct() {
   struct structure *test_struct = new structure;
   struct ret = *test_struct;

   delete test_struct;
   return ret;
}
```